# Regex to pick out key information between words/characters

Tags: regex

I have a string as follows:

```
players: 2-8
```

Using regex how would I match the 2 and the 8 without matching everything else (ie 'players: ' and the '-')?

I have tried:

```
players:\s*([^.]+|\S+)
```

However, this matches the entire phrase and also uses a '.' at the end to mark the end of the string which might not always be the case.

It'd be much better if I could use the '-' to match the numbers, but I also need it to be looking ahead from 'players' as I will be using this to know that the data is correct for a given variable.

Using python if that's important

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use 2 capture groups instead `players:\s*(\d+)-(\d+)\b`

Comment: This is still matching the entire phrase, it's not just matching the 2 and the 8? Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the regex flavor, but you could do it like this `(?<=\bplayers: (?:\d+-)?)\d+`https://regex101.com/r/Srjak7/1 or `(?:\bplayers:\h+|\G(?!^))-?\K\d+` https://regex101.com/r/govabI/1 What is the tool or language?

Comment: Ah yes, that second example worked! Using python. Thanks!

Comment: For the second example, you have to use the PyPi `regex` module. It will not work with `re`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `players:\s*([^.]+|\S+)` will use a single capture group matching either any char except a dot, or match a non whitespace char. Combining those, it can match any character.

---

To get the matches only using, you could make use of the Python PyPi [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you can use the `\G` anchor:

```
(?:\bplayers:\s+|\G(?!^))-?\K\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bplayers:\s+` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match, then match `players:` and 1+ whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Anchor to assert the current position at the end of the previous match to continue matching
- `)` Close non capture group
- `-?\K` Match an optional `-` and forget what is matched so far
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/govabI/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourWMFWQakgJ7EytajYSsFI10KJqyCxpCS1KA8oUaSkYW8VkwSTjinWrolx17BXjNPU1LWP8Y5J0QaqLsrMK9EAm6aXlpmXkpiTowE1QUehWFPz/38A)

```
import regex

s = "players: 2-8"
pattern = r"(?:\bplayers:\s+|\G(?!^))-?\K\d+"
print(regex.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['2', '8']
```

---

You could also use a approach using 2 capture groups with `re`

```
import re

s = "players: 2-8"
pattern = r"\bplayers:\s+(\d+)-(\d+)\b"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('2', '8')]
```